# Extending Euler's sine product formula to integers

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, infinite-product

I have derived the following series for $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$
$$
\pi \cot(\pi t) = \frac{1}{t} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2z}{z^2-k^2},
$$
and from that through uniform convergence and integration proved
$$
\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \Big( 1-\frac{t^2}{k^2} \Big),
$$
again for $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

The question is how could I now extend the Euler's product formula to the whole $\mathbb{R},$ so also to the integers, rigorously? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS can clearly be extended to a continuous function of $t$ defined on all of $\Bbb{R}$ (at $t=0$, define it to be $1$). The RHS is continuous since the product converges normally on compact subsets of $\Bbb{R}$. Continuous functions which agree on a dense set agree everywhere, thus both sides are equal on all of $\Bbb{R}$.

In fact, from here, if you replace $t\in\Bbb{R}$ by $z\in\Bbb{C}$, then both sides actually define entire functions, and of course, entire functions which agree on $\Bbb{R}$ agree on all of $\Bbb{C}$, so the same formula holds on $\Bbb{C}$ as well.

Comment: Great explanationT Thank you a lot.

Comment: Sorry one more question. What do you mean by product being normally convergent?

Comment: @Bombadil well, I could have just as well said "converges uniformly on compact subsets" THe reason is that if $t$ varies in a compact (hence bounded) set $K$, say of radius $M$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sup\limits_{t\in K}\left|\frac{t^2}{k^2}\right|\leq M^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}<\infty$ (this is a well-known condition to check for uniform convergence of a product).

Comment: I see. Thank you.